# Scene builder not open after adding my own TextFiled

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx, scenebuilder

My problem is about opening scene builder from eclipse.
I want to display a text field that accepts only numbers and I found nice way to implement it by a class that extends text field and overrides method "replace text with 3 parameter" , with a condition.
After creating the object by my controller class and adding it to a layout FXML file by passing ID.

***When I change the tag in FXML file from TextField TO NumberTextField after than I run app and it work fine. When I use Eclipse and open layout by scene builder it will not open unless I change the tag from NumberTextField    TO TextField it open.***

Here my class NumberTextField & the part of FXML file which contain tag.

**class:**

```
package application;

import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

public class NumberTextField extends TextField{

   public NumberTextField() {
       this.setPromptText("Enter the value");
   }

   @Override
   public void replaceText(int start, int end, String text) {
      if(text.matches("[0-9]")|| text.isEmpty()){
         super.replaceText(start, end, text);
      }
   }
}
```

FXML:

```
 <NumberTextField  fx:id="fromTextField" prefWidth="170.0" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
  <NumberTextField  fx:id="toTextField" disable="true" prefWidth="170.0" promptText="Value" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
```

Please note : I did import at the first in FXML for NumberTextFiled.
Sorry for talk to much .
Please help me !!!!!!
Have a good day.

Edite:
this is error message that i got .
[image]
[image]

this is custom componentNumberTextField
[image]

Comment: Does Scene Builder show any exception? like - `Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: NumberTextField`

Comment: Yes it do . Wait i will upload it now .sorry for that.

Comment: Apologies for the late reply. This exception is telling you that Scene Builder doesn't have the definition of  `NumberTextField`. You need to export your custom control as a JAR and import it in Scene Builder.

Comment: I did it , and i have it in custom control section and i can drag and drop component !!!

Comment: sorry for that but problem is still here ,,,, but if i open new file with scene builder and open the file that contain NumberTextField it is open.
what i mean is from eclipse not working , but normally i can open it !!!!.
and thank's for your concern.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have problem while running the application or while creating the FXML?

Comment: no, wrote it above. But my problem scene builder not opening from eclipse

Comment: So, it opens from the Scene Builder app but doesn't open from eclipse?

Comment: yes it is . and i do not way and i did every things in right way .
i know it is not big problem but you know when working in big projects it will consume time .

Comment: Although I am not an eclipse user but this doesn't look right. Can you confirm that the Scene Builder when you uploaded the custom control and the Scene Builder used by eclipse are the same?

Comment: Ok,I will edit Question